# How to replace the current cell value with a value that is maximum of the current and previous cell in a column in a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame, and want to run the following code (which is correct) much faster to reduce the processing time.
Logic: I want to sort the values in every column in increasing (cumulative) order, but when a 'zero row' (ex: 5th row) is encountered, that row is to be skipped (code: if row2 == 0: continue). If the 2nd cell (row2) value is lower than the previous one (row1), then 2nd cell value is replaced by the first one. I want to make this code run faster. If the below code is used, then iterating through df having a shape of (1305 cols, 3000 rows) takes around 1.5 minutes for completion. Need help in this regard to reduce the processing time.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A1': [118.0, 189.0, 154.0, 129.0, 0, 227.0, 208.0, 200.0, 733.0, 804.0,
           861.0],
    'A2': [108.0, 54.0, 122.0, 148.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 838.0, 996.0, 987.0],
    'A3': [70.0, 89.0, 107.0, 148.0, 0, 149.0, 241.0, 222.0, 825.0, 954.0,
           1138.0],
    'A4': [80.0, 40, 117.0, 158.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 700, 899, 850]
})

for i in df.columns:
    for j in range(len(df) - 1):
        row1 = df[i][j]
        row2 = df[i][j + 1]
        # print(row1, row2)
        if row2 == 0:
            continue
        elif row2 - row1 < 0:
            # print('true')
            df[i][j + 1] = df[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC then this will solve your problem

```
def transform_col(series):
    return series.groupby(series.eq(0).cumsum()).cummax()

df.apply(transform_col)
```

result

```
       A1     A2      A3     A4
0   118.0  108.0    70.0   80.0
1   189.0  108.0    89.0   80.0
2   189.0  122.0   107.0  117.0
3   189.0  148.0   148.0  158.0
4     0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
5   227.0    0.0   149.0    0.0
6   227.0    0.0   241.0    0.0
7   227.0    0.0   241.0    0.0
8   733.0  838.0   825.0  700.0
9   804.0  996.0   954.0  899.0
10  861.0  996.0  1138.0  899.0
```

Comment: Perfect. This code is 100x faster than my code. Thanks a lot for the code. It saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I accepted it. But I don't have 15 reputations to cast a vote. But the feedback is recorded.